# Add a condition to run a gulp watch

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, gulp

I have a gulp watch task as following:

```
gulp.task("watch", () => {
  const watch = {
    'dev': [src_folder + '**/*.njk', src_js_folder + '**/*.js'],
    'css': [src_sass_folder + '**/*.scss']
  }
  gulp.watch(watch.dev, gulp.series("dev")).on("change", browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch(watch.css, gulp.series("sass"));

});

gulp.task("dev", gulp.series("merge-json", "nunjucks", "sass", "js"));
```

So when there's any changes on `*.sass` files the `sass` task will run, and when there's changes on `*.js` and/or `*.njk` files the task `dev` will run.

The problem I'm having is when there are changes on `*.sass`, `*.js` and/or `*.njk` at the same time, the `sass` task will run twice in this case.

How can I skip the `gulp.watch(watch.css, gulp.series("sass"));` when the   `gulp.watch(watch.dev, gulp.series("dev")).on("change", browserSync.reload);` is already run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

The double execution of the `sass` task when running the `watch` task occurs because in the code you have shared you are effectively defining the `sass` task to run twice.

```
gulp.task("watch", () => {
    const watch = {
        'dev': [src_folder + '**/*.njk', src_js_folder + '**/*.js'],
        'css': [src_sass_folder + '**/*.scss']
    }

    // 1st execution > The `dev` task is defined into the `gulp.series()` as part
    // of the combined tasks to run for this watcher, and, as `dev` contains the
    // `sass` task in it this will run it the first time.
    gulp.watch(watch.dev, gulp.series("dev")).on("change", browserSync.reload);
    
    // 2nd execution > This watcher have the `sass` task defined into the
    // `gulp.series()` as part of the combined tasks to run, this will run
    // the second time
    gulp.watch(watch.css, gulp.series("sass"));
});

// The `dev` task contains the`sass` task into the `gulp.series()` as part
// of the combined tasks to run
gulp.task("dev", gulp.series("merge-json", "nunjucks", "sass", "js"));
```

Therefore, every time you run `gulp dev` the `sass` task will be executed only once, and every time you run `gulp watch` the `sass` task will be executed twice.

### Solution

To solve this problem you could perhaps reorder the executions in a slightly different way. Here are some ideas of what some possible solutions might look like.

**- Possible Solution 1**

```
const paths = {
    njk: src_folder + '**/*.njk',
    js: src_js_folder + '**/*.js',
    sass: src_sass_folder + '**/*.scss'
}

gulp.task("watch", () => {
    gulp.watch([
            paths.njk,
            paths.js,
            paths.sass
        ],
        gulp.series("dev")
    ).on("change", browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task("dev", gulp.series("merge-json", "nunjucks", "sass", "js"));
```

In this example, we define the `sass` task as part of the combined tasks to run defined within the `gulp.series` for the `dev` task. This will allow us to run `gulp dev` and execute all those tasks only once. It will also allow us to run `gulp watch` and execute the tasks defined for the `dev` task only once each time the files defined in `paths` are updated.

**- Possible Solution 2**

```
const paths = {
    njk: src_folder + '**/*.njk',
    js: src_js_folder + '**/*.js',
    sass: src_sass_folder + '**/*.scss'
}

gulp.task("watch", () => {
    gulp.watch([
            paths.njk,
            paths.js,
        ],
        gulp.series("dev")
    ).on("change", browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch(paths.sass, gulp.series("sass");
});

gulp.task("dev", gulp.series("merge-json", "nunjucks", "js"));

gulp.task("another_extra_task", gulp.series("dev", "sass"));
```

In this example, we removed the `sass` task from the combined tasks to run for the `dev` task, also, we defined the `another_extra_task` task where we are combining the `dev` and `sass` tasks. This will allow us to run `gulp another_extra_task` and execute all the combined tasks defined for `dev` and the `sass` task, but also, it will allow us to run `gulp watch` without repeating the execution of the `sass` task since in the first watcher we execute the `dev` task where the `sass` task isn't defined anymore and we just execute it with the second watcher.

### Conclusion

Since the definition of the tasks depends on each particular use case, I recommend you try to reorder the execution of them in a more granular way. See the following reference which explains how to avoid duplicating tasks https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/series#avoid-duplicating-tasks

I hope these possible solutions help you to understand the problem you are having in the code you have shared!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is due to rapid file changes, it may help to set the watch `delay` option:

`gulp.watch(watch.dev, { delay: 500 }, gulp.series("dev"))`

If that does not help, you may need to figure out a way to de-bounce the events. There's an old package called [gulp-debounce](https://github.com/mnzaki/gulp-debounce) which seems to achieve that, but is unmaintained and so is likely incompatible, but viewing its source may grant some insights.